# How to add the compiler command lines in the makefile to the source code

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, comments

When I execute several different compilation commands via a makefile on one specific sourcecode (c-code). Is there a way to add these compilation commands as a comment to the source code for documentation reason?

Comment: I think you can use sed to replace a string (ie "{compile cmd}") somewhere in a doc-block of your source. However, I am not sure if you can get the current makefile rule as string... you might need to manually create a string with all the commands (in which as I understand you need variables to be expanded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but this doesn't seem too difficult:

```
foo.o: foo.cc
    @command="$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@"; echo $$command ;\
  sed -i .bak "1{x;s|^|//$$command|;G;}" $< ; \
  $$command
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by adding a preprocessor macro defined as a string containing the compiler flags, and then use this macro in an assignment to a constant string pointer.

Something like this in the Makefile

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -DCFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" ...
```

And in one source file do e.g.

```
const char cflags[] = CFLAGS;
```

---

There is no generic way to get it as a part of a comment though.

You could have a special marker in a comment block in a source file, and replace that using e.g. [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) in a POSIX enviromnent (like Linux or OSX).

Something like this:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's@// CFLAGS: .*$@// CFLAGS: $(CFLAGS)@' some_source_file.c
```

Comment: This will insert the information into the char array right? I am looking for a way to get these information in form of commented lines on top of the source file. Is this possible?

Comment: @Maxi No it's not really possible to add as a comment in a generic way. Updated my answer with one possible solution.